# Send Multiple datas to PHP from a table

Tags: php, html

everybody! I need your help to solve my newbie problem. i've a table that show some file listed inside a folder and i've, if selected, add the file path,name, category and tags to DB.

I usually use php to send single information like 1 username, 1 name or something like that. Now i've those multiple lines that i don't know in wich form send to php and how to manage then the insert into the db. Anyone can help? this is my table.

```
<table border="1" bordercolor="#000" width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
    <tr>
        <td>File Name</td>              
        <td>File Size</td>              
        <td>Tags</td>
        <td>Category</td>
        <td><button id="checkUncheck">Select All / Deselect All</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>File2</td>              
        <td>8 MB</td>               
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="null">--</option>
                <option value="test1">test1</option>
                <option value="test2">test2</option>
                <option value="test3">test3</option>
                <option value="test4">test4</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <td class="check_uncheck"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>File2</td>              
        <td>8 MB</td>               
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="null">--</option>
                <option value="test1">test1</option>
                <option value="test2">test2</option>
                <option value="test3">test3</option>
                <option value="test4">test4</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <td class="check_uncheck"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>File2</td>              
        <td>8 MB</td>               
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="null">--</option>
                <option value="test1">test1</option>
                <option value="test2">test2</option>
                <option value="test3">test3</option>
                <option value="test4">test4</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <td class="check_uncheck"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

when i press submit the DB will be updated with every file checked in the table.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your database. Also how do you currently insert into the database? As a loop may be all that's necessary here.

Comment: the thing is that at start i would send it via ajax to php. but i don't know in wich form. i've to take them all and send as json? or make an array? the db is like : file name - tags - category - path ; all are varchar

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that in each table row you have three select or other input field. 
Each row will look like this (simplified example):

```
<tr><td><input type="text" name="username[]"></td><td><select name="usertype[]"></td><td><input type="text" name="nickname[]"></td></tr>
```

The form field name ends with [] as you can see. This is to post all the values as an array and not overwrite them.

When you will post the form you will get that:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$usertype = $_POST['usertype'];
$nickname = $_POST['nickname'];
```

is an array (and the same for all the other inputs.

Next step is easy:

```
foreach($username as $key=>$value){
    $current_username = $username[$key];
    $current_usertype = $usertype[$key];
    $current_nickname = $nickname[$key];
    //now you insert the single row as usual;
}
```